# Jetpack Compose OutlinedTextField adds extra padding to the leadingIcon. Is there a way to remove it?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I can't figure out where this extra padding comes from.  I even added a green background to the Icon to make sure the icon wasn't taking up any space.  I read that singleLine can affect inner padding, but setting it to true/false didn't make a difference.

```
OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = modifier
      .fillMaxWidth()
    value = textFieldValue,
    onValueChange = { newText ->
      textFieldValue = newText
    },
    leadingIcon = if (isCurrency) {
      {
        Icon(
          imageVector = Icons.Filled.AttachMoney,
          contentDescription = null
        )
      }
    } else null,
```

The screenshot is using the same OutlinedTextField for all fields.  The one without the extra padding has the leadingIcon set to null.  Any ideas how to remove the padding?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can use the **`prefix`** attribute instead of the `leadingIcon`:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { newText ->
        text = newText
    },
    prefix  =
        {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.AttachMoney,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        },

)
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, my OutlinedTextField doesn't have a preFix.  I'm using the Material 3 one, perhaps that is the reason?

Comment: @MartyMiller Yes it requires M3 1.1.0

Comment: @MartyMiller It's called leadingIcon now I believe.

Comment: @Varundroid leadingIcon and prefix are different.